# Solving an equation involving binomial coefficients and complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, binomial-coefficients, summation

**Question:**

Solve the following equation for $x$:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^{k}\cos(k\theta )=0$$

**Attempt:**

I think this equation come from:

$$(x\cos\theta+ix\sin\theta)^{k}$$

Is that right?

I don't know what to do after that.

Comment: You're close. I believe the sum in question is the real part of $(1 + xe^{ix})^n$. Haven't double checked, though.

Comment: Hint: replace $\cos(k\theta)$ by $e^{ik\theta}$ and use the binomial theorem (the answer will be the real part of this).

Comment: Please check $n$ and $k$ is the question. May be there is a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $x,\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$:

$$\sum _{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}{x}^{k}\cos \left( k\theta \right) =\frac{1}{2}
 \left( 1+x{{\rm e}^{i\theta}} \right) ^{n}+\frac{1}{2} \left( 1+x{{\rm e}^{
-i\theta}} \right) ^{n}=0,$$
$$\Rightarrow\dfrac{
 \left( 1+x{{\rm e}^{i\theta}} \right) ^{n}}{\left( 1+x{{\rm e}^{
-i\theta}} \right) ^{n}}=-1={\rm e}^{i\pi},$$
$$\dfrac{
 \left( 1+x{{\rm e}^{i\theta}} \right)}{\left( 1+x{{\rm e}^{
-i\theta}} \right)}={\rm exp}\left({\dfrac{im\pi}{n}}\right):m \,\text{odd}\in \mathbb{Z},$$
$$x=\dfrac{\sin \left( {\dfrac {\pi m}{2n}} \right)}{\sin \left( 
\theta-{\dfrac {\pi m}{2n}} \right) }.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{0\le r\le n}\binom nkx^ke^{ik\theta}=(1+xe^{i\theta})^n=(1+x\cos\theta+ix\sin\theta)^n$$

Let $1+x\cos\theta=R\cos\alpha,  x\sin\theta=R\sin\alpha$

$$R^2=(1+x\cos\theta)^2+(x\sin\theta)^2=1+x^2+2x\cos\theta$$

$$\implies \cos\alpha=\frac{1+x\cos\theta}{\sqrt{1+x^2+2x\cos\theta}}$$

$$\implies (1+x\cos\theta+ix\sin\theta)^n=\{R(\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha)\}^n=R^n(\cos n\alpha+i\sin n\alpha)$$

So, we need either $R=0$ or $\cos n\alpha=0$

If $R=0, x\sin\theta=1+x\cos\theta=0$

Case $1:$ If $x=0, 1+x\cos\theta=1\ne0\implies x\ne0$

Case $2:$ If $\sin\theta=0,\cos\theta=\pm1,1\pm x=0\implies x=\mp1 $

Else $R\ne0 ,\cos n\alpha=0\implies n\alpha=(2m+1)\frac{\pi}2$ where $m$ is any integer

Now we need to solve for $x,\theta$ from $$\cos (2m+1)\frac{\pi}{2n}=\frac{1+x\cos\theta}{\sqrt{1+x^2+2x\cos\theta}}$$

Comment: Please disclose the mistake here